# getting the value of a particluar field of DB

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to get a particular value of a field from the DB. But why i try to get the value it gives me the error:

Message: Undefined index: status_status_id

Part of my controller:

```
     function get_by_id($id = 0){


   $data['info'] = $this->Rfetch1_model->getdata_by_id($id);
   $r=$data['status_status_id'];

    if ($r==0){

         //something....
}
```

My model:

```
   function getdata_by_id($id = 0){
    $this->db->where('id',$id);

    $sql = $this->db->get('info');

    return $sql->result();
}
```

From my understanding my model will return everything from the 'info' table where id=$id;
Then why it cannot get the value of the field status_status_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to access it as:

```
$r=$data['info'][0]->status_status_id;
```

`$sql->result()` will return an array of row objects.

Alternatively, you could return `$sql->row()` from `getdata_by_id()` and then access it as:

```
$r=$data['info']->status_status_id;
```

Comment: but now it says   
Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: controllers/Rfetch1_controller.php

Answer (score 0):

check this

controller

```
function get_by_id($id = 0){


   $data['info'] = $this->Rfetch1_model->getdata_by_id($id);
   $r=$data['info']->status_status_id;

    if ($r==0){

         //something....
}
```

Model

```
function getdata_by_id($id = 0){
    $this->db->where('id',$id);

    $sql = $this->db->get('info');

    return $sql->row();
}
```

Comment: Thanks..but if i return only $sql->row()->status_status_id then i loose other information (like register_id etc.) of that particular id.I want to get all the information and do some extra things by checking on the status_status_id.